# How to use the output of one loop in another iteration?

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

So I am trying to build a program of a hangman which would ask the user for his inputs and after each try would use his answers

```
for i in range(0, 3):
    print("\nTRY NO. ", end='')
    print(i + 1)
    alphabet = input()
    if alphabet in words_list[ind]:
        for u in words_list[ind]:
            if alphabet == u:
                print(alphabet, end='')
            else:
                print("_", end='')
```

Till here the output for a word like QWWERTY and if the user entered W would be something like *WW*__.
What should I do to keep this result and have the user enter his input for *WW*__ in his 2nd try i.e. his previous attempt's result is visible to him.

```
    ans = input()
    if ans == words_list[ind]:
        print("YOU SAVED HIM, YOU SAVED THE MAN!!!")
        break
    else:
        print("BETTER LUCK NEXT TIME")
        flag = flag + 1
        continue

else:
    print("SORRY WRONG WORD, TRY AGAIN!")
```

Sorry for the description but this is my first question, would really appreciate if answered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use a list declared outside of the for loop to keep track of which letters where guessed:

```
guessed_letters = []
for i in range(3):
    print("\nTRY NO. ", end='')
    print(i + 1)
    alphabet = input()
    guessed_letters.append(alphabet)
    for u in words_list[ind]:
        if u in guessed_letters:
            print(alphabet, end='')
        else:
            print("_", end='')
```